# NodeJS Express multiple route file through one route file

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning NodeJS. I have a nodeJS API project. I want to use version in routes so i created following folder structure.

```
application/    
    --app.js
    --routes/
    ----V1/
    ------routes.js
    ------users.js
```

Here is my app.js file:

```
 var v1 = require('./routes/v1/route');

 app.use('/api/v1', v1.router);
```

And this is route.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/',function(req,res){    
    res.send("Welcome to Node JS V1");
});

var courses = require('./users').router;
-- How to include usres route here

module.exports.router = router;
```

users.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/',function(req,res){    
    res.send("Get all users.");
});


module.exports.router = router;
```

Now how i can call users from route.js file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd do it a bit different than @Shaharyar

**routes.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Welcome to Node JS V1');
});

router.use('/users', require('./users').router);

module.exports.router = router;
```

**users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/',function(req, res){    
  res.send('Get all users.');
});

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  // Create user
  res.send('Some response.');
});

module.exports.router = router;
```

---

To simplify it I'd drop the `.router` on `module.exports` and do.

```
router.use('/users', require('./users'));
```

Also the same for the route.js file, then in your server.js or wherever:

```
router.use('/api/v1', require('./routes'));
router.use('/api/v2', require('./routes2'));
```

Comment: Exactly the way i wanted. Thanks :).

Comment: Your approach seems very clean but don't you think you're creating too many `express` instances? Why do this when it can be done using only one instance?

Comment: @Shaharyar modules are cached in **node**. The **express** module exposes the `createApplication` factory (`var app = express()`) and some other stuff including the `Router` constructor.

Comment: I know modules are cached. But instances are not, and it creates a new instance `var router = express.Router()` if I am not wrong. I was pointing to it.

Answer (score 8):

You should create express instance once and pass it into all modules.

**route.js file**

```
//initialize
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){    
    res.send("Welcome to Node JS V1");
});

//modules
require('./users')(router);
require('./sessions')(router);  //added for explaination
require('./comments')(router);  //added for explaination

//export
module.exports.router = router;
```

**module file** *(any module users, comments etc)*

```
//initialize
module.exports = function (router) {
    router.get('/users', users);
}

//APIs
function users(req, res) {    
    res.send("Get all users.");
}
```

Comment: This is showing error that "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" in the module file (users.js), for router.get.

Comment: Try now, I've referenced `router` from inside.

Comment: How does this look when you're loading a ton of packages like mongodb, cron jobs, mandrill emails, etc? Are you passing like 12 variables to all of the sub modules? Is there a better way to set this up so all of these are global and can automatically be referenced from anywhere without having to write all of this glue-code?

Comment: @CorySchulz No you don't have to inject all the packages **from** main file **to** sub modules. You just require those packages inside the module, wherever you need them. You can ask a separate question, explaining your scenario and I will explain.