# How to add Express route endpoints from another .js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express app whose `server.js` file has maybe 30 GET and POST endpoints, like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http_port = 8000;

app.listen(http_port,()=>{
 console.log(`app listening on port ${http_port}`);
});

app.get('/create_something',function(req,res){
 createSomething();
 res.send('create');
});

app.post('/update_something',function(req,res){
 updateSomething();
 res.send('update');
});

//and so on for 30 more endpoints
```

For ease of maintenance, I want to break this set of endpoints up into different files, e.g. `video.js` and `audio.js`.

Thinking [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41187557/619177) might help, I created another file `other_route.js`:

```
var express=require('express');
var router=express.Router();

router.get('/other_route_endpoint',function(req,res){
    res.send('other_route_endpoint');
});

module.exports.router=router;
```

and then including this in `server.js` by changing my initial declarations to:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http_port = 8000;
var router=express.Router();
router.use('/other_route',require('./other_route').router);
```

But when I visit `myserver.com:8000/other_route_endpoint`, I get this error:

```
Cannot GET /other_route_endpoint
```

How can I add in endpoints from other files into `server.js`, so I can move some of its many endpoints into these subfiles?

Comment: you should visit `myserver.com:8000/other_route/other_route_endpoint`

Comment: @BearNithi got this response: `Cannot GET /other_route/other_route_endpoint`

Comment: Try change to `app.use('/other_route',require('./other_route').router);`

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your main file should not be using a router. Change the line to `app.use('/other_route',require('./other_route').router);`.

Second: each path you set with `router.use` in the routing file will be *relative to* the path specified in `app.use`. See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router

For example, if you have this in your main file

```
app.use('/foo', require('./bar.js'));
```

And this in `bar.js`

```
router.get('/bar', /* do something */);
```

Then the corresponding endpoint would be `/foo/bar`.

Comment: If I want to put `bar.js` in a subfolder `xyxy`, how do I include it?  `app.use('/foo',require('./xyxy/bar.js'));`?

Comment: @sigil Yes, that is correct. See https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules for more details.