# Node.js: Centralize multiple routes into one route file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am trying to centralize all of my route file into a index file and place that index route file in my main app file. I am trying to follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41182313/nodejs-express-multiple-route-file-through-one-route-file)

I have added app.js file. And the routes/ folder below:

When i am trying to get any of the url as mentioned below, it's showing the 404 error.

app.js:

```
const indexRouter  = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

routes file:

```
-- index.js
-- author.js
-- book.js
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Get Home Page of The Web Application
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Library Home Page');
});

router.use('/author', require('./author').router);
router.use('/book', require('./book').router);

module.exports = router;
```

author.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

var AuthorController = require('../controllers/authorController');

router.get('/', AuthorController.authorList);

router.get('/:id', AuthorController.authorDetail);

router.get('/create', AuthorController.authorCreateForm);

module.exports = router;
```

book.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

var BookController = require('../controllers/bookController');

router.get('/', BookController.bookList);

router.get('/:id', BookController.bookDetail);

router.get('/create', BookController.bookCreateForm);

module.exports = router;
```

I want to access the url as follows:

```
Home:
/

Author:
/author/
/author/1
/author/create

Book:
/book/
/book/1
/book/create
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`module.exports = router` is a default export so `require('./author').router` refers to an undefined property on the router, it should be:

```
router.use('/author', require('./author'));
```

And in your server entry:

```
app.use(indexRouter); // No `'/'` as first param
```

Comment: Try `app.use(indexRouter)`, I would call that something like appRouter or serverRouter too

Comment: Update:
const appRouter = require('./routes/index'); app.use(indexRouter);

done! it works. 

But, i am not sure, how to route the home page. can you please suggest how to work with home page? Its showing 404 error

Comment: Hm the `Library Home Page` looks ok to me not sure what is going wrong there sorry

Comment: Yes, that was okay. Forget to restart the server. Thats why, showed 404 error